# Invoke a function multiple times with the same argument JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a "Secret Santa" function that takes an array of names and matches them randomly with other names in the same array (and they can't match with themselves).

I've got the initial portion working, but now I need to make it so it runs the function twice, and then make sure no one gets the same person two years in a row.  For the life of me, I cannot get the function to run twice and create two separate outputs (except with console.log, but since I need to compare the outputs that won't help me).

Code:

```
var family = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff', 'ggg', 'hhh', 'iii']

function secretSanta() {
var yourPick = [];
var receivers = family.slice();
var length = family.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  var giver = family[i];
  var receiverIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * receivers.length);
     while (receivers[receiverIndex] === giver) {

       receiverIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * receivers.length);
     }
     var receiver = receivers.splice(receiverIndex, 1)[0];
    yourPick.push({
      Giver: giver,
      Receiver: receiver
    });
}
return yourPick;
}
secretSanta()
```

I've tried iteration

```
for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) secretSanta(i)
```

Recursion

```
(function repeat(number) {
    secretSanta(number);
    if (number < 3) repeat(number + 1);
})(1);
```

and functor application

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach(secretSanta);
```

But I either get undefined, an infinite loop, or "maximum stack size exceeded"

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: Can't you just call it twice, storing each result in its own variable? Also, your understanding of the terminology seems to be off. Your `secretSanta` function does not accept any arguments.

Comment: I tested your code on this fiddle and it worked https://jsfiddle.net/fhuk5nar/1/ what is the problem you are having?

Comment: You're right Pedro!  I have no idea, I may have not tried that and thought that I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All possible different pairs in random order.

```js
var family = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff', 'ggg', 'hhh', 'iii']


var pairs = [];

for(let i = 0; i<family.length; i++){
    for(let j = i+1; j<family.length; j++){
    pairs.push([family[i], family[j]])
    }    
}

while(pairs.length){
    let pair = Math.floor(Math.random() * pairs.length)
    let temp = pairs.splice(pair,1);
    if(Math.floor(Math.random()*2)) temp[0].reverse()//<-- pair order
    console.log(temp[0].join(" - "))
}
```

The while is just to pick the pairs randomly.